# Prove $\det(A+BC)=\det(A+CB)$ if $AB=BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be three endomorphisms of a finite-dimensional vector space such that $AB=BA$. Prove that
$$\det\left(A+BC\right)=\det\left(A+CB\right)$$

Comment: Did you make any effort to start the proof on your own?

Comment: Replacing $A$ by $A + \epsilon \operatorname{id}$ for some $\epsilon$ in the ground field (or an extension, if necessary) allows you to WLOG assume that $A$ is invertible. Then you can use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844204/prove-that-detxi-m-ab-xm-n-detxi-n-ba?rq=1 . I think there is a better solution, though.

Comment: This works for all fields: apply the [determinant formula for block matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/361849/1551) to $\pmatrix{C&-I\\ A&B}$ twice, once using the commutativity of the pair of matrices on bottom row and once using the commutativity of the two sunblocks on the right.

Answer (score 6):

First assume that $B$ is invertible. We then have $$A = B^{-1}AB$$ and

$$\det(A+BC) = \det(B^{-1}(A+BC)B) = \det(B^{-1}AB + CB) = \det(A + CB)$$

Since invertible matrices are dense and determinant is continuous, equality extends to non-invertible $B$'s by continuity.

Answer (score 0):

To see this, note that:

1) $\det(A+BC)=\det(A)\det(I+A^{-1}BC)$,

2) $AB = BA$ implies $BA^{-1}=A^{-1}B$,

3)  $\det(I+ABC)=\det(I+BCA)$ (this is true for any cyclic permutation of $ABC$).

Combining these gives us: $$\det(A+BC)=\det(A)\det(I+BA^{-1}C)=\det(A)\det(I+A^{-1}CB)= \det(A+CB).$$

*Note: we have implicitly assumed that $A$ is invertible.*

Comment: No, endomorphisms need not be invertible.

Comment: Sorry, yes. That's an automorphism!